# Front wheel buzzing intermittently

Tags: wheels

Just tried fixing up a 2007 Land Rover Kaikas MTB, that cost £400 (about $530) when it was new. The front wheel makes an intermittent buzzing sound, that usually lasts around 2 - 5 seconds, and might not be heard for up to a few minutes - or sometimes soon after. This occurs at any time on flat terrain, so it's not got anything to do with going over bumps. Though I did notice when coming downhill fast on the road, I could feel vibration through the wheel. Because it's so irregular, I'm inclined to not think it's the bearing adjustment (I've tried a loose-ish and tight quick release to quickly see if changes in the bearings made much difference, I don't think it did). The wheel spins nice and freely without play in the bearings. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have the opportunity to try out a borrowed wheel, you can limit the cause to the wheel.

Comment: Does it have disk brakes?

Comment: It does have disc brakes

Comment: The deep tread tires may have lots of mud on them that is unlikely to be perfectly balanced. Could maybe be this? After you accelerate on a good road, the mud flies away.